# Foreach Loop PHP Once Stop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Currently I have a script that will collect data from an array and push it to an API, but for some reason i cant get it to add more then one at a time.

**$data Array**

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 0
            [_source] => App
            [_source_id] => 790006230e91dd6279a42a814bf5965a.jpg
            [_client_ids] => 2
            [_parent_ids] => 0
            [_image] => blank.jpg
            [_title] => test1
            [_body] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 1
            [_source] => App
            [_source_id] => b3a5a6df0cf1dfc30882b20f8a493092.jpg
            [_client_ids] => 2
            [_parent_ids] => 0
            [_image] => blank.jpg
            [_title] => test2
            [_body] => test2
        )

)
```

**PHP**

```
public function save($data) {

        $submissionManager = new SubmissionManager($this->container);

        $returndata = array();

        foreach( $data as $entry )
        {

           $this->mustBeGranted('PERM_SUBMISSION_CREATE');

           $saved = array();

           $client_ids = explode(',', $entry['_client_ids']);
           $parent_ids = explode(',', $entry['_parent_ids']);
           $length = count($client_ids);

           for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                   $input = array_merge($entry, array(
                        'client_id' => isset($client_ids[$i]) ? $client_ids[$i] : 0,
                         'parent_id' => isset($parent_ids[$i]) ? $parent_ids[$i] : 0,
                        '_source_id' => $entry['_source_id']
                    ));
                    $saved[] = $submissionManager->createSubmission($input);
           }
           $returndata[ $entry['_id']] = $saved;
        }

    }
```

Basically it will only push the first array to the API and not the second one even though I've added a for-each.

Comment: What does `$returndata` look like, and when do you actually do the saving?

Comment: What exactly are you intending to be accomplished by your use of `explode()`? In both of your inner arrays, both `_client_ids` and `_parent_ids` are single integers. Is there some case where those will be a comma-separated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $saved=array() from foreach loop and put it before the loop. You are assigning empty array each time loop starts

Comment: I think he is returning `$returndata` so clearing `$saved` actually helps in his case.

Comment: It seems to be normal to empty the saved array ? It's just used for the 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its likely that the value of `$entry['_id']` is not changing so you are reassigning to the same array key.

Try instead using simply:

`$returndata[] = $saved;`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry fixed issue it was something to do with my createSubmission  class... my bad